# Selection does not contain main type

Tags: java, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

whenever I wanted to run the prog I get above error,  using eclipse so basically I tried almost everything while using boolean any solution

```
package class;

public class My {
    public  boolean sleep In(boolean weekday, boolean vacation) {
          if (!weekday || vacation) {
            return true;
          }

          return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method name has a space in it - `boolean sleep In` should probably be `boolean sleepIn`. You can also just `return (!weekday || vacation)` rather that use an `if`.

Comment: You need a `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Comment: yes i knw that thats not a prob, its posting correction so i did like that,.

Comment: Polywhirl where i should add public static void main(String[] args), i added before but it was not executing.

Answer (score 1):

Java application needs a main method as the entry point. So add a main method and start your program execution. The main method  signature is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

> The modifiers public and static can be written in either order (public
>   static or static public), but the convention is to use public static
>   as shown above. You can name the argument anything you want, but most
>   programmers choose "args" or "argv".

Read further to understand the basic structure of a java application: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: package myClass; public class My { public static void main(String[] args){ public boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation) { if (!weekday || vacation) { return true; } return false; } } }// if i put main agrs then i face 6 errors bcos like//illegal modidfier sleepIn//syntax error token expected//void method cannot return any value.

Comment: Your method has to be OUTSIDE the `main` method. The `main` method instead should CALL the `sleepIn` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for a start:

```
package myClass; 

public class My
{
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        My prog = new My();
        System.out.println("Sleep: " + prog.sleepIn(true, false));
    }

    public boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation) {
        return (!weekday || vacation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @JunedAhsan said you need a `main` method, which is the entry point to your application. In this method you then have to call your `sleepIn` method or create a new instance of you `My` class...
So in yourr case you would have something like this:

```
public class My
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println(sleepIn(false, true));
    }

    public boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation) {
      if (!weekday || vacation) {
           return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
}
```

I suggest you to read some tutorials about the java basics. It is not to hard to learn the basics/the language itself. And the rest is practice (IMHO).